# Diffeomorphism on the Sphere

Tags: analysis

Suppose $f:S^2\rightarrow S^2$ is a diffeomorphism. Is true that $f$ must have a fixed point or a point $x\in S^2$ such that $f(f(x))=x$?

Comment: Yes. Have you learned the Lefschetz fixed point theorem yet?

Comment: No, give me some reference please @DavidSpeyer

Comment: Have you learned what cohomology is? If so, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lefschetz_fixed-point_theorem isn't bad.

Comment: Is there a more analytic way to solve this problem? Because i got it in a course of dynamical systems @DavidSpeyer

Comment: Not that I see. But I'm sure there are other approaches in the world. I'll leave it there.